# How to change background image of specific div with 'onclick' function in React.JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, background

Thanks for helping my needy butt. 
I am working with ReactJS and trying to get a div to change it's background from a color to a specific image url on click of a button in a modal.
I have tried many things and keep getting this error:
 **TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null**

I successfully console.log the image URL and div ID within the onclick function, but the div styling is getting nowhere...All help is appreciated!

Here is my button

```
<button onClick={() => { this.changeUserBG(this.state.AlexPics[0], "one") }} className="btn btn-danger">Kaalia of the Vast</button>
```

here is the function I call

```
  changeUserBG = (imageUrl, userArea) => {
        let thisOne = document.getElementById(userArea);
        console.log(thisOne)
        thisOne.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
        // document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundImage = `require(url(${imageUrl}))`;

    }
```

Here is the div area I am trying to manipulate:

```
<div className="col-6" id="one">

       <div className="">

         <p className="lifeArea">
          <button className="minusOne" onClick={() => { 
              this.subtractOne("playerOne") }}>-1</button>
             <span id="playerOne">40</span>
             <button className="plusOne" onClick={() => { 
             this.addOne("playerOne") }}>+1</button>
         </p>

{/* Theme Modal that has ASK sub modals */}
<p className="bgCheckButton">
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalScrollable">Theme</button>
</p>
</div>
```

wanna talk mtg? down for that too!

Comment: It looks like the div is not found while accessing its style. You must adjust the code to ensure that the div exists at that moment.

Comment: Since I am only calling the function on button click shouldn't it not check until it is clicked?

Comment: For the record, manually doing things like `document.getElementById(userArea);` in react code is _strongly_ discouraged, I'd recommend looking at a react tutorial if you're new to it. Assuming you know what you're doing though - the error implies that `<span id="playerOne"></span>` isn't available on the page when you click the -1 button. I'd suggest verifying that it exists with dev tools before clicking it. I'd be willing to bet that it's not the div you were expecting, but a 3/3 Elk instead.

Comment: @JackFranklin If your goal is to secure the process, two options for you: 1. Disable the button until the div is added somehow. 2. Check the existence of the div in the click handler every time.

Comment: Is it possible that there is an issue with the `this` binding? I know that the primary advantage to using An arrow `()=> {...}` over `function()` is that the arrow locks the `this` context. (But I stick by "Never expect this to be what you think this is")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react, you should not use `getElementById` or any method changing the dom.
You could have something like this:

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: this.state.image}}>...</div>
```

So whenever you do:

```
this.setState({ image: 'some_value.png' });
```

the background image will be updated automatically.

In your case, if you need to change different div background based on div ID, you could store a map in your state, something like this:

```
clickHandler = (divId, color) => {
   this.setState(state => ({ backgroundColors: { [divId]: color, ...state.backgroundColors} }));
}
```

The line of code above might be hard to understand at first if you are not used to the spread operator, but what it does is actually simple: it adds a new key to map `backgroundColors` stored in the state.

And you would use it as such:

```
<div id="foo" style={{ backgroundImage: this.state.backgroundColors["foo"]}}>...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use React `ref` api to get the refrence of the div and then you can change the style property of the div.

**Sample Code**

**In Class constructor**

```
constructor() {
  this.userAreaRef = React.createRef();
}

changeUserBG = (imageUrl, userArea) => {
  let thisOne = this.userAreaRef;
  console.log(thisOne)
  thisOne.current.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
}
```

**Render**

```
 <div ref={this.userAreaRef} className="col-6" id="one">
            <div className="">
                <p className="lifeArea">
                    <button className="minusOne" onClick={()=> { 
this.subtractOne("playerOne") }}>-1</button>
                    <span id="playerOne">40</span>
                    <button className="plusOne" onClick={()=> { 
this.addOne("playerOne") }}>+1</button>
                </p>
                {/* Theme Modal that has ASK sub modals */}
                <p className="bgCheckButton">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalScrollable">Theme</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**In functional component**

```
const someFunction = () => {
  const userAreaRef = useRef();

  changeUserBG = (imageUrl, userArea) => {
    let thisOne = userAreaRef;
    console.log(thisOne)
    thisOne.current.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  }

  return (
    <div ref={this.userAreaRef} className="col-6" id="one">
            <div className="">
                <p className="lifeArea">
                    <button className="minusOne" onClick={()=> { 
this.subtractOne("playerOne") }}>-1</button>
                    <span id="playerOne">40</span>
                    <button className="plusOne" onClick={()=> { 
this.addOne("playerOne") }}>+1</button>
                </p>
                {/* Theme Modal that has ASK sub modals */}
                <p className="bgCheckButton">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalScrollable">Theme</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using a reference here ? You should not use a reference when you do not need to, this is a react principle.

Comment: I agree with you but it's not wrong, you can use React `ref` api.  If you don't want to maintain the state. Could you share some reference where React team is mentioning that we should not use `Ref`

Comment: The fact that you can does not mean you should :) Here is a link to react doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
It clearly says `Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.`